# need to separate a keylistener from a class into another

Tags: java, eclipse, class, keylistener

so i'm programming on java, and i'm running into troubles when trying to implement a keylistener into a different class, so i have this class named GUI, and a txtbox called convertir. when it executes on GUI it doesn't allow user to type any letter only allow the user to type numbers.

```
txtConvertir = new JTextField();
            txtConvertir.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {


                public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evento) {

                    // método que impide que las letras sean ingresadas en el text
                    // box
                    char c = evento.getKeyChar();

                    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                        evento.consume();

                    }

            });


            txtConvertir.setBounds(158, 44, 224, 20);
            panel.add(txtConvertir);
            txtConvertir.setColumns(10);
```

then i have another class into a different package called main, and a method called validarprecio.

```
void validarprecio(){

}
```

Could someone help me to move the method from GUI to validarprecio method, so it still works on the gui? Please i have searched in the web but i don't understand. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Program to the Interface

You can't (generally) name your method `validarprecio`, instead it should be `keyTyped` and `extend` from `KeyAdapter` as in your inner class example. For example,

```
class ValidarPrecio extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evento) {
        char c = evento.getKeyChar();
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
            evento.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

and then you could write something like

```
txtConvertir = new JTextField();
ValidarPrecio validarprecio = new ValidarPrecio();
txtConvertir.addKeyListener(validarprecio);
```

Comment: omg, thank you very much you saved my life! it works nice and smooth! Thank you!!!

Comment: @DanielEstebanLadinoTorres Happy to help. Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). And if this answers your question please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/243725).

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch ok i will do!